# UICollectionView - redesign in Landscape mode

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am working on a `UICollectionView` to show list of items in `Portrait` mode as shown in below screen shot and implemented using `UICollectionViewController`.

[image]

Now I want to re-design same thing in `Landscape` mode as shown in below screen shot.

[image]

How can I get such a design using `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` in `Landscape` mode by re-using same code base of portrait? Is it possible? can you please advice me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think using `UISplitViewController` is better for this kind of display, in landscape mode u can show both master and detail, in portrait u can show only detail screen.

Comment: in landscape, left(cell1 & header) and right(cell2 cell3 cell4) both are scrollable??

Comment: @elk_cloner, Thanks for your reply. Not both. In landscape only cell2 cell3 cell4 are scrollable.

Comment: @ShankarBS, Thanks for your reply. Actually some people has designed it for portrait by using UICollectionViewController. I am thinking to re-use their code instead of starting it from scratch.

Comment: I don't think it's possible.You have to design for landscape separately.

Comment: u can reuse the same code for both viewcontroller's without changing but u need to set the splitviewcontroller and adjust the width of master and detail screen.

Comment: @ShankarBS, If I use SplitViewController then it has left side table view and right side detail view, but I need it in reverse way. So is it possible to make it reverse? Can we show left side detail view and right side table view?

Comment: Both Detail and master view in splitViewController  are viewcontrollers tou can display what ever you want. To answer your question Yes its possible

Comment: @GaneshGuturi , yes since both are view controllers you can reverse it and handle it accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do by using stackview. Create a stackview with two views then change the axis when orientation change. Set proper constraints for your requirement.

```
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    handleOrientationForLandscape(isLandscape: UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape)
  }
  func handleOrientationForLandscape(isLandscape: Bool)  {

    if isLandscape
    {
      containerStackview.axis = .horizontal
      topViewWidthConstraint.constant = 700

    }else
    {
      containerStackview.axis = .vertical
      topViewWidthConstraint.constant = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    }

  }
```

please check https://github.com/karthikprabhuA/stackOverflowAnswer

[image]

[image]